# Can scrapy be used to scrape dynamic content from websites that are using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, screen-scraping, scrapy

I have recently been learning Python and am dipping my hand into building a web-scraper.  It's nothing fancy at all; its only purpose is to get the data off of a betting website and have this data put into Excel.

Most of the issues are solvable and I'm having a good little mess around. However I'm hitting a massive hurdle over one issue. If a site loads a table of horses and lists current betting prices this information is not in any source file. The clue is that this data is live sometimes, with the numbers being updated obviously from some remote server. The HTML on my PC simply has a hole where their servers are pushing through all the interesting data that I need.

Now my experience with dynamic web content is low, so this thing is something I'm having trouble getting my head around.

I think Java or Javascript is a key, this pops up often.

The scraper is simply a odds comparison engine.  Some sites have APIs but I need this for those that don't. I'm using the scrapy library with Python 2.7

I do apologize if this question is too open-ended. In short, my question is: how can scrapy be used to scrape this dynamic data so that I can use it?  So that I can scrape this betting odds data in real-time?

---

<sub>See also: [How can I scrape a page with dynamic content (created by JavaScript) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520) for the general case.</sub>

Comment: How can I get this data, the data that is dynamic and live?

Comment: If your page have javascript, [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047666/how-to-combine-scrapy-and-htmlunit-to-crawl-urls-with-javascript)

Comment: Try on some `Firefox` extensions like `httpFox` or `liveHttpHeaders` and load a page which is using ajax request. Scrapy does not automatically identify the ajax requests, you have to manually search for the appropriate ajax URL and then do request with that.

Comment: cheers, i'll give the Firefox extensions a wizz

Comment: There's a number of open source solutions. But if you're looking for an easy and quick way to do this especially for large workloads, check out SnapSearch (https://snapsearch.io/). It was built for JS, HTML5 and SPA sites requiring search engine crawlability. Try the demo (if there's empty content, this means the site actually returned no body content, potentially meaning a 301 redirect).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Webkit based browsers (like Google Chrome or Safari) has built-in developer tools. In Chrome you can open it `Menu->Tools->Developer Tools`. The `Network` tab allows you to see all information about every request and response:

[image]

In the bottom of the picture you can see that I've filtered request down to `XHR` - these are requests made by javascript code.

*Tip: log is cleared every time you load a page, at the bottom of the picture, the black dot button will preserve log.*

After analyzing requests and responses you can simulate these requests from your web-crawler and extract valuable data. In many cases it will be easier to get your data than parsing HTML, because that data does not contain presentation logic and is formatted to be accessed by javascript code.

Firefox has similar extension, it is called [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Some will argue that firebug is even more powerful but I like the simplicity of webkit.

Comment: How the heck can this be an accepted answer if it doesn't even have the word 'scrapy' in it??

Comment: It works, and it's easy to parse using json module in python. It's a solution!

Compared to that, try using selenium or other stuff people are suggesting, it's more headache. If the alternative method was way more convoluted then I'd give it to you, but it's not the case here @Toolkit

Comment: This is not really relevant. The question was how to use scarpy to scrape dynamic web sites.

Answer (score 104):

Here is a simple example of  `scrapy` with an AJAX request. Let see the site [rubin-kazan.ru](https://web.archive.org/web/20130114061720/http://www.rubin-kazan.ru/guestbook.html).

All messages are loaded with an AJAX request. My goal is to fetch these messages with all their attributes (author, date, ...):

[image]

When I analyze the source code of the page I can't see all these messages because the web page uses AJAX technology. But I can with Firebug from Mozilla Firefox (or an equivalent tool in other browsers) to analyze the HTTP request that generate the messages on the web page:

[image]

It doesn't reload the whole page but only the parts of the page that contain messages. For this purpose I click an arbitrary number of page on the bottom:

[image]

And I observe the HTTP request that is responsible for message body:

[image]

After finish, I analyze the headers of the request (I must quote that this URL I'll extract from source page from var section, see the code below):

[image]

And the form data content of the request (the HTTP method is "Post"):

[image]

And the content of response, which is a JSON file:

[image]

Which presents all the information I'm looking for.

From now, I must implement all this knowledge in scrapy. Let's define the spider for this purpose:

```
class spider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'RubiGuesst'
    start_urls = ['http://www.rubin-kazan.ru/guestbook.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        url_list_gb_messages = re.search(r'url_list_gb_messages="(.*)"', response.body).group(1)
        yield FormRequest('http://www.rubin-kazan.ru' + url_list_gb_messages, callback=self.RubiGuessItem,
                          formdata={'page': str(page + 1), 'uid': ''})

    def RubiGuessItem(self, response):
        json_file = response.body
```

In `parse` function I have the response for first request.
In `RubiGuessItem` I have the JSON file with all information.

Comment: Hi. Could you please explain what 'url_list_gb_messages' is? I can't understand it. Thanks.

Comment: This one definitely is better.

Comment: @polarise That code is using the `re` module (regular expressions), it searchs for the string `'url_list_gb_messages="(.*)"'` and isolates the content of parentheses in the variable of same name. This is a nice intro: https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html

Comment: it retrieves for me a body with "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

Answer (score 44):

Many times when crawling we run into problems where content that is rendered on the page is generated with Javascript and therefore scrapy is unable to crawl for it (eg. ajax requests, jQuery craziness).

However, if you use Scrapy along with the web testing framework Selenium then we are able to crawl anything displayed in a normal web browser.

Some things to note:

- You must have the Python version of Selenium RC installed for this to work, and you must have set up Selenium properly.  Also this is just a template crawler.  You could get much crazier and more advanced with things but I just wanted to show the basic idea.  As the code stands now you will be doing two requests for any given url.  One request is made by Scrapy and the other is made by Selenium.  I am sure there are ways around this so that you could possibly just make Selenium do the one and only request but I did not bother to implement that and by doing two requests you get to crawl the page with Scrapy too.
- This is quite powerful because now you have the entire rendered DOM available for you to crawl and you can still use all the nice crawling features in Scrapy.  This will make for slower crawling of course but depending on how much you need the rendered DOM it might be worth the wait.

  ```
  from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
  from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
  from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
  from scrapy.http import Request

  from selenium import selenium

  class SeleniumSpider(CrawlSpider):
      name = "SeleniumSpider"
      start_urls = ["http://www.domain.com"]

      rules = (
          Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\.html', )), callback='parse_page',follow=True),
      )

      def __init__(self):
          CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
          self.verificationErrors = []
          self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.domain.com")
          self.selenium.start()

      def __del__(self):
          self.selenium.stop()
          print self.verificationErrors
          CrawlSpider.__del__(self)

      def parse_page(self, response):
          item = Item()

          hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
          #Do some XPath selection with Scrapy
          hxs.select('//div').extract()

          sel = self.selenium
          sel.open(response.url)

          #Wait for javscript to load in Selenium
          time.sleep(2.5)

          #Do some crawling of javascript created content with Selenium
          sel.get_text("//div")
          yield item

  # Snippet imported from snippets.scrapy.org (which no longer works)
  # author: wynbennett
  # date  : Jun 21, 2011
  ```

Reference: http://snipplr.com/view/66998/

Comment: Neat solution! Do you have any tips on connecting this script to Firefox? (OS is Linux Mint). I'm getting "[Errno 111] Connection refused".

Comment: This code no longer works for `selenium=3.3.1` and `python=2.7.10`, error when importing selenium from selenium

Comment: In that version of selenium your import statement would be:    `from selenium import webdriver` or `chromedriver` or whatever you happen to be using. [Docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)   EDIT: Add documentation reference and change my horrible grammar!

Comment: Selenium Remote Control has been replaced by Selenium WebDriver, according to [their website](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 36):

Another solution would be to implement a download handler or download handler middleware. (see [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=download%20middleware) for more information on downloader middleware) The following is an example class using selenium with headless phantomjs webdriver:

*1)* Define class within the `middlewares.py` script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class JsDownload(object):

    @check_spider_middleware
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='D:\phantomjs.exe')
        driver.get(request.url)
        return HtmlResponse(request.url, encoding='utf-8', body=driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'))
```

*2)* Add `JsDownload()` class to variable `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARE` within `settings.py`:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'MyProj.middleware.MiddleWareModule.MiddleWareClass': 500}
```

*3)* Integrate the `HTMLResponse` within `your_spider.py`. Decoding the response body will get you the desired output.

```
class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    # define unique name of spider
    name = "spider"

    start_urls = ["https://www.url.de"] 

    def parse(self, response):
        # initialize items
        item = CrawlerItem()

        # store data as items
        item["js_enabled"] = response.body.decode("utf-8")
```

**Optional Addon:** 
I wanted the ability to tell different spiders which middleware to use so I implemented this wrapper:

```
def check_spider_middleware(method):
@functools.wraps(method)
def wrapper(self, request, spider):
    msg = '%%s %s middleware step' % (self.__class__.__name__,)
    if self.__class__ in spider.middleware:
        spider.log(msg % 'executing', level=log.DEBUG)
        return method(self, request, spider)
    else:
        spider.log(msg % 'skipping', level=log.DEBUG)
        return None

return wrapper
```

for wrapper to work all spiders must have at minimum:

```
middleware = set([])
```

to include a middleware:

```
middleware = set([MyProj.middleware.ModuleName.ClassName])
```

**Advantage:** 
The main advantage to implementing it this way rather than in the spider is that you only end up making one request. In A T's solution for example: The download handler processes the request and then hands off the response to the spider. The spider then makes a brand new request in it's parse_page function -- That's two requests for the same content.

Comment: I was quite a bit late to answering this though >.<

Comment: @rocktheartsm4l what's wrong with just using, in `process_requests` , `if spider.name in ['spider1', 'spider2']` instead of the decorator

Comment: @pad There is nothing wrong with that. I just found it more clear for my spider classes to have a set named middleware. This way I could look at any spider class and see exactly which middlewares would be executed for it. My project had a lot of middleware implemented so this made sense.

Comment: This is a terrible solution. Not only it's not related to scrapy but the code itself is extremely inefficient as well as the whole approach in general defeats the whole purpose of asynchronous web scraping framework that is scrapy

Comment: Its much more efficient than any other solution I've seen on SO as using a downloader middle ware makes it so only one request is made for the page.. if it's so terrible why dont you come up with a better solution and share instead of making blatently one sided claims. "Not related to scrapy" are you smoking something? Other than implementing some crazy complex,  robust and custom solution this is the approach I've seen most people use. Only difference is that most implement the selenium part in the spider which causes multiple requests to be made...

Answer (score 11):

I was using a custom downloader middleware, but wasn't very happy with it, as I didn't manage to make the cache work with it.

A better approach was to implement a custom download handler.

There is a working example [here](https://github.com/flisky/scrapy-phantomjs-downloader/blob/master/scrapy_phantomjs/downloader/handler.py). It looks like this:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.signalmanager import SignalManager
from scrapy.responsetypes import responsetypes
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from selenium import webdriver
from six.moves import queue
from twisted.internet import defer, threads
from twisted.python.failure import Failure


class PhantomJSDownloadHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.options = settings.get('PHANTOMJS_OPTIONS', {})

        max_run = settings.get('PHANTOMJS_MAXRUN', 10)
        self.sem = defer.DeferredSemaphore(max_run)
        self.queue = queue.LifoQueue(max_run)

        SignalManager(dispatcher.Any).connect(self._close, signal=signals.spider_closed)

    def download_request(self, request, spider):
        """use semaphore to guard a phantomjs pool"""
        return self.sem.run(self._wait_request, request, spider)

    def _wait_request(self, request, spider):
        try:
            driver = self.queue.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(**self.options)

        driver.get(request.url)
        # ghostdriver won't response when switch window until page is loaded
        dfd = threads.deferToThread(lambda: driver.switch_to.window(driver.current_window_handle))
        dfd.addCallback(self._response, driver, spider)
        return dfd

    def _response(self, _, driver, spider):
        body = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerHTML")
        if body.startswith("<head></head>"):  # cannot access response header in Selenium
            body = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.textContent")
        url = driver.current_url
        respcls = responsetypes.from_args(url=url, body=body[:100].encode('utf8'))
        resp = respcls(url=url, body=body, encoding="utf-8")

        response_failed = getattr(spider, "response_failed", None)
        if response_failed and callable(response_failed) and response_failed(resp, driver):
            driver.close()
            return defer.fail(Failure())
        else:
            self.queue.put(driver)
            return defer.succeed(resp)

    def _close(self):
        while not self.queue.empty():
            driver = self.queue.get_nowait()
            driver.close()
```

Suppose your scraper is called "scraper". If you put the mentioned code inside a file called handlers.py on the root of the "scraper" folder, then you could add to your settings.py:

```
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    'http': 'scraper.handlers.PhantomJSDownloadHandler',
    'https': 'scraper.handlers.PhantomJSDownloadHandler',
}
```

And voilà, the JS parsed DOM, with scrapy cache, retries, etc.

Comment: I like this solution!

Comment: Nice solution. Is Selenium driver still the only option?

Comment: Great solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @ivan , I did exactly like your answer. But, the response is not arriving at spider's parse(callback) method. When I check the response body inside the handler, it's as expected. Where can be the issue? Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Vipool, it's been a while I don't run this code... I'm using nodejs' https://sdk.apify.com/docs/examples/crawl-multiple-urls to crawl with js parsing lately.

Comment: Hello @Motheus, please check my previous comment to Vipool.

Answer (score 3):

> how can scrapy be used to scrape this dynamic data so that I can use
>   it?

I wonder why no one has posted the solution using Scrapy only.

Check out the blog post from Scrapy team [SCRAPING INFINITE SCROLLING PAGES](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/06/22/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-june-2016/)
. The example scraps http://spidyquotes.herokuapp.com/scroll website which uses infinite scrolling.

The idea is to **use Developer Tools of your browser and notice the AJAX requests, then based on that information create the requests for Scrapy**.

```
import json
import scrapy


class SpidyQuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spidyquotes'
    quotes_base_url = 'http://spidyquotes.herokuapp.com/api/quotes?page=%s'
    start_urls = [quotes_base_url % 1]
    download_delay = 1.5

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        for item in data.get('quotes', []):
            yield {
                'text': item.get('text'),
                'author': item.get('author', {}).get('name'),
                'tags': item.get('tags'),
            }
        if data['has_next']:
            next_page = data['page'] + 1
            yield scrapy.Request(self.quotes_base_url % next_page)
```

Comment: We face the same problem again : Scrappy is not made for this purpose and this is where we get confronted to the same issue. Move on to phantomJS or as others suggested, create your own download middleware

Comment: @rak007 PhantomJS vs Chrome driver. Which one would you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

Data that generated from external url which is API calls HTML response as POST method.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'  
    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://howlongtobeat.com/search_results?page=1'
        payload = "queryString=&t=games&sorthead=popular&sortd=0&plat=&length_type=main&length_min=&length_max=&v=&f=&g=&detail=&randomize=0"
        headers = {
            "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36"
        }

        yield scrapy.Request(url,method='POST', body=payload,headers=headers,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        cards = response.css('div[class="search_list_details"]')

        for card in cards: 
            game_name = card.css('a[class=text_white]::attr(title)').get()
            yield {
                "game_name":game_name
            }
           

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process =CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(TestSpider)
    process.start()
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few more modern alternatives in 2022 that I think should be mentioned, and I would like to list some pros and cons for the methods discussed in the more popular answers to this question.

1. The top answer and several others discuss using the browsers `dev tools` or packet capturing software to try to identify patterns in response `url`'s, and try to re-construct them to use as `scrapy.Request`s.

   - Pros: This is still the best option in my opinion, and when it is available it is quick and often times simpler than even the traditional approach i.e. extracting content from the HTML using `xpath` and `css` selectors.
   - Cons: Unfortunately this is only available on a fraction of dynamic sites and frequently websites have security measures in place that make using this strategy difficult.
2. Using `Selenium Webdriver` is the other approach mentioned a lot in previous answers.

   - Pros: It's easy to implement, and integrate into the scrapy workflow. Additionally there are a ton of examples, and requires very little configuration if you use 3rd-party extensions like `scrapy-selenium`
   - Cons: It's slow!  One of scrapy's key features is it's asynchronous workflow that makes it easy to crawl dozens or even hundreds of pages in seconds. Using selenium cuts this down significantly.

There are two new methods that defenitely worth consideration, `scrapy-splash` and `scrapy-playwright`.

**[scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)**:

- A scrapy plugin that integrates [splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash), a javascript rendering service created  and maintained by the developers of scrapy, into the scrapy workflow. The plugin can be installed from pypi with `pip3 install scrapy-splash`, while splash needs to run in it's own process, and is easiest to run from a docker container.

**[scrapy-playwright](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright)**:

- Playwright is a browser automation tool kind of like `selenium`, but without the crippling decrease in speed that comes with using selenium. Playwright has no issues fitting into the asynchronous scrapy workflow making sending requests just as quick as using scrapy alone. It is also much easier to install and integrate than selenium. The `scrapy-playwright` plugin is maintained by the developers of scrapy as well, and after installing via pypi with `pip3 install scrapy-playwright` is as easy as running `playwright install` in the terminal.

More details and many examples can be found at each of the plugin's github pages https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright and https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash.

p.s.  Both projects tend to work better in a linux environment in my experience. for windows users i recommend using it with [The Windows Subsystem for Linux(wsl)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Scrapy can scrape dynamic websites, website that are rendered through JavaScript.

There are Two approaches to scrapy these kind of websites.

1. you can use `splash` to render Javascript code and then parse the rendered HTML.
   you can find the doc and project here [Scrapy splash, git](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)
2. as previously stated, by monitoring the `network calls`, yes, you can find the API call that fetch the data and mock that call in your scrapy spider might help you to get desired data.

Answer (score -1):

I handle the ajax request by using Selenium and the Firefox web driver. It is not that fast if you need the crawler as a daemon, but much better than any manual solution.