# Need help in parsing an ajax form request with the help of python-scrapy

Tags: python, ajax, scrapy

Even though I am new to **scrapy framework**, I am able to write good spiders using scrapy. Recently I came across [this page](http://www.doogal.co.uk/LatLong.php), where by entering address, and on submit I have to capture the latitude and longitude. Could any one help?

This code works for normal post requests:

```
return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
                    callback=self.after_login)]
```

But what about the ajax based form requests, like the above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8550114/248296

Answer (score 0):

This site uses Google Maps Geocode to fetch the data, so it's more easy to just use Google's API's.

It was requesting:

```
Request URL:http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4s12%20Street%2C%20New%20York%2C%20NY&7sUS&9sen-US&callback=_xdc_._8xnwgc&token=93301
```

You might as well just [sign up for the Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) and query them yourself :)