# Pagination using scrapy

Tags: python, request, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl this website:
http://www.aido.com/eshop/cl_2-c_189-p_185/stationery/pens.html

I can get all the products in this page, but how do I issue the request for "View More" link at the bottom of the page?

My code till now is:

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="normalLeft"]/div/a',unique=True)),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@id="topParentChilds"]/div/div[@class="clm2"]/a',unique=True)),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//p[@class="proHead"]/a',unique=True)),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('http://[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+$', ), deny=('/about-us/about-us/contact-us', './music.html',  ) ,unique=True),callback='parse_item'),
)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you should take a look at this thread on how to deal with scraping ajax dynamically loaded content: 
[Can scrapy be used to scrape dynamic content from websites that are using AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax)

So, clicking on "View More" button fires up an XHR request:

```
http://www.aido.com/eshop/faces/tiles/category.jsp?q=&categoryID=189&catalogueID=2&parentCategoryID=185&viewType=grid&bnm=&atmSize=&format=&gender=&ageRange=&actor=&director=&author=&region=&compProductType=&compOperatingSystem=&compScreenSize=&compCpuSpeed=&compRam=&compGraphicProcessor=&compDedicatedGraphicMemory=&mobProductType=&mobOperatingSystem=&mobCameraMegapixels=&mobScreenSize=&mobProcessor=&mobRam=&mobInternalStorage=&elecProductType=&elecFeature=&elecPlaybackFormat=&elecOutput=&elecPlatform=&elecMegaPixels=&elecOpticalZoom=&elecCapacity=&elecDisplaySize=&narrowage=&color=&prc=&k1=&k2=&k3=&k4=&k5=&k6=&k7=&k8=&k9=&k10=&k11=&k12=&startPrize=&endPrize=&newArrival=&entityType=&entityId=&brandId=&brandCmsFlag=&boutiqueID=&nmt=&disc=&rat=&cts=empty&isBoutiqueSoldOut=undefined&sort=12&isAjax=true&hstart=24&targetDIV=searchResultDisplay
```

which returns `text/html` of the next 24 items. Note this `hstart=24` parameter: first time you click "View more" it's equal to 24, second time - 48 etc..this should be your lifesaver.

Now, you should simulate these requests in your spider. The recommended way to do this is to instantiate scrapy's [Request](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) object providing callback where you'll extract the data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This was helpful, but an example of how to "instantiate scrapy's request object" would have been even more helpful.