# Scraping ajax pages using python

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

I've already seen [this question about scraping ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260540/how-do-you-screen-scrape-ajax-pages), but python isn't mentioned there. I considered using [scrapy](http://blog.scrapy.org/), i believe they have some docs on that subject, but as you can see the website is down. So i don't know what to do. I want to do the following:

I only have one url, example.com you go from page to page by clicking submit, the url doesn't change since they're using ajax to display the content. I want to scrape the content of each page, how to do it?

Lets say that i want to scrape only the numbers, is there anything other than scrapy that would do it? If not, would you give me a snippet on how to do it, just because their website is down so i can't reach the docs.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First of all, scrapy docs are available at https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

Speaking about handling ajax while web scraping. Basically, the idea is rather simple:

- open browser developer tools, network tab
- go to the target site
- click submit button and see what [`XHR` request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) is going to the server
- simulate this `XHR` request in your spider

Also see:

- [Can scrapy be used to scrape dynamic content from websites that are using AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax)
- [Pagination using scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129071/pagination-using-scrapy/16133788#16133788)

Hope that helps.

Comment: i was referring to this url `blog.scrapy.org/scraping-ajax-sites-with-scrapy‎` which is no longer available, thanks for reminding me of readthedocs.com

Comment: Got it. If you have problems with the spider implementation, consider posting another question with what url are you trying to crawl, what button to click etc. Happy scraping!

Comment: @Lynob here's the URL you're talking about: https://web.archive.org/web/20130525095330/http://blog.scrapy.org/scraping-ajax-sites-with-scrapy

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer very useful but I would like to make it more simple.

```
response = requests.post(request_url, data=payload, headers=request_headers)
```

request.post takes three parameters url, data and headers. Values for these three attributes can be found in the XHR request.

Copy the whole request header and form data to load into the above variables and you are good to go

Comment: What if I can't find the XHR request? It's not visible in Chrome or FoxFox webtools. However, there is an AJAXSetup.js file. Is there any other way to find that information?