# Crawling tables from webpage

Tags: python, html, web-crawler, lxml, scrape

I'm trying to extract csu employee salary data from this webpage (http://www.sacbee.com/statepay/#req=employee%2Fsearch%2Fname%3D%2Fyear%3D2013%2Fdepartment%3DCSU%20Sacramento). I've tried using urlib2 and requests library, but none of them returned the actual table from the webpage. I guessed the reason could be that the table was generated dynamically by javascript. Below is my code using requests.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get("http://www.sacbee.com/statepay/#req=employee%2Fsearch%2Fname%3D%2Fyear%3D2013%2Fdepartment%3DCSU%20Sacramento")
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
name = tree.xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()'
```

Any help/comments will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you inspect the page, the info's actually a JSON file. I hope you know what this means. :D

Comment: Thanks Nanashi! I know how to handle json files, but could you point me to the json file? I was not able to find the url to the json file within the webpage.

Comment: The URL is `http://api.sacbeelabs.com/v1/statepay/employee/search/name=/year=2013/department=CSU%20Sacramento.json`. However, you need to make a POST request for this, because it'll just return the following in Python: `{u'status': {u'message': u'Unauthorized', u'code': 401, u'reason': u'Client origin not specified'}, u'request': {u'verb': u'statepay/employee/search/name=/year=2013/department=CSU%20Sacramento', u'params': [], u'format': u'json'}}
`.

Comment: Hi Nanashi, how did you find the json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt on it, as per my comment. Note that I only pulled out one line of data. All else is up to you.

**Code:**

```
import requests as rq

url = "http://api.sacbeelabs.com/v1/statepay/employee/search/name=/year=2013/department=CSU%20Sacramento.json"
data = "74XoegZ494trsvrus_As4B4handjZ494-Adl4B4olg494dnnk933pppAmWYXaaAYjh3mnWnakWq3-Ela-B-Oahkgjqaa07tw8tJmaWlYd07tw8tJiWha07tw8uH07tw8tJqaWl07tw8uHtrsu07tw8tJZakWlnhain07tw8uHGT-107tw8trTWYlWhainj4B4labalal494dnnk933mnWYfj-8albgjpAYjh3-Boamnejim3tt_v_rt_3YlWpgeic1nWXgam1bljh1paXkWca4B4nenga494TnWnaDVjlfalDTWgWlqDTaWlYdD1DUdaDTWYlWhainjDFaaBDTWYlWhainjBDGWgebjlieW4B4mYlV49sxzrB4mYlL49srwrB4peiV49sxzrB4peiL49_stB4oW4974Wcain494Oj-CeggW3wArD-I-6ss-MD-1Xoino-MDNeio-AD-Azx2xv-MDl-89tzAr-JDKaYfj3trsrrsrsDJelabj-A3tzAr4B4njoYd49bWgmaB4Zjh4954mnjlWca4B4WiehWneji4B4YWi-8WmtZ4B4paXmjYfan4B4pjlfal4B4WoZej4B4-8eZaj4B4m-8c4B4cajgjY46B4Ymm4954WiehWneji4B4nlWimbjlh468B4omal4974Woi494Koamn488"
headers = {
'Host': 'api.sacbeelabs.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'X-SBAPI-Auth-Token': '0QNWbefXw6fQQcWXqK8vDw',
'X-SBAPI-SID': '3gbRqglHXAVDy1vwdcVVMf',
'X-SBAPI-CID': '2HuWho39ZcDUlTswYSWUd9',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'Referer': 'http://www.sacbee.com/statepay/',
'Content-Length': '684',
'Origin': 'http://www.sacbee.com',
'Cookie': 'sbapi-cid=2HuWho39ZcDUlTswYSWUd9; sbapi-sid=3gbRqglHXAVDy1vwdcVVMf',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Pragma': 'no-cache',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
}

r = rq.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
json_data = r.json()

base = json_data["result"]["employees"][0] # First employee.

name = base["name"]
first_name = name["first"]
last_name = name["last"]

pay = base["pay"]["total"]

title = base["title"]
dept = base["department"]

print first_name, last_name, pay, title, dept
# Your turn here...
```

**Result:**

```
Clayton Abajian 9844 Lecturer - Academic Year CSU Sacramento
[Finished in 0.9s]
```

Comment: Many thanks! May I know what 'data' is in your code?

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. Anyway, data is simply the POST parameter I got from inspecting via Firebug.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nanashi! It worked after some poking around.. I didn't figure out which parameter you used for "data" so I skip the data parameter for the rq.post, but it still works.

Answer (score 2):

Just took a quick look on the website you mentioned. It is indeed due to the fact that the table is loaded in using javascript. SO it is not actually part of the website you are requesting in your script.

To fix this, you'll probably have to look into the webrequests made by the website and find the one that retrieves the data of the table. It is not hard too do, just a nuisance. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax); similar question. Hope it helps!