# How to extract data from table `tr` and `td`?

Tags: python

I want to crawl a website here is a link (http://legacy-assignments.uspto.gov/assignments/q?db=pat&qt=rf&reel=044841&frame=0221&pat=&pub=&intn=&asnr=&asnri=&asne=&asnei=&asns=) which containd table tr and td .
If i change the reel and frame from url then the result changes so i want to make a module in which i run a loop and all the data is crawled. But I stucked in looping or  I am new to crawl html parser website.

Please help me to find out the perfect code for this website.
I give input in reel and frame from csv and i know how to do that i just want to  know how to extract data from html parser

Here is my code:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from time import sleep
import csv
import re
from lxml import html
import lxml.html

doc=lxml.html.parse("http://legacy-assignments.uspto.gov/assignments/q?db=pat&qt=rf&reel=044841&frame=0221&pat=&pub=&intn=&asnr=&asnri=&asne=&asnei=&asns=")

for row in doc.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr'):


    try:
        reelframe1=row.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a/text()')[0]
        reelframe=reelframe1.strip().encode('utf8')
        print reelframe
    except:
        print error
    try:
        recorded1=row.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/text()')[0]
        recorded= recorded1.strip().encode('utf8')
        print recorded
    except:
        print error
    try:
        attorney1=row.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/span/text()')[0]
        attorney =attorney1.strip().encode('utf8')
        print attorney
    except:
        print error

    try:
        conveyance1=row.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/span/text()')[0]
        conveyance= conveyance1.strip().encode('utf8')
        print conveyance
    except:
        print error

    try:
        totalproperties1=row.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/text()')[0]
        totalproperties= totalproperties1.strip().encode('utf8').replace('                          ','').replace('Total properties:','').strip()   
        print totalproperties
    except:
        print error


    try:
        patent1=row.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a/text()')[0]
        patent= patent1.strip().encode('utf8')
        print patent              
    except:
        print error

    try:
        issuedate1=row.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div/text()')[0]
        issuedate = issuedate1.strip().encode('utf8')
        print issuedate
    except:
        print error


    try:
        application1=row.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/div/text()')[0]
        application=application1.strip().encode('utf8')
        print application
    except:
        print error

    try:
        filing=row.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/div/text()')[0]
        filingdate=filing.strip().encode('utf8')
        print filingdate
    except:
        print error

    try:
        publication=row.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/a/text()')[0]
        publicationno=publication.strip().encode('utf8')
        print publicationno
    except:
        print error

    try:
        pubdt=row.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/div/text()')[0]
        publicationdate=pubdt.strip().encode('utf8')
        print publicationdate
    except:
        print error

    try:
        title1=row.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/text()')[0]
        title=title1.strip().encode('utf8')
        print title
    except:
        print error
```

Comment: Please properly format your code, and if you're able to better narrow down the part of it that isn't working and only post that, it would go a long way. As it stands right now it's hard to answer your question

Comment: I want to crawl table data from given website for multiple reelframes which is changed in urls @TankorSmash

Comment: @TankorSmash But i do not exactly know hot to crawl data from td and tr because the data i want are in tr and td. i want tha data seperated in multiple columns

Comment: Give an example of your code's output, or describe the output. Does the code generate errors? Does it access the wrong tables and fields? Does it output empty data, or random data, or not run at all?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949029/crawling-tables-from-webpage

Comment: I dont have any errors in output i just want to know how to loop in xpath or in tabe data

Comment: Is anyone going to help me in this