# scrapy: how to catch the unexpected case of return a response with Partial html body and status 200

Tags: scrapy

During my crawling, some pages return a response with partial html body and status 200, after I compare the response body with the one I open in browser, the former one miss something.
How can I catch this unexpected partial response body case in spider or in download middleware?

Below is about the log example：

2014-01-23 16:31:53+0100 [filmweb_multi] DEBUG: Crawled (408) http://www.filmweb.pl/film/Labirynt-2013-507169/photos> (referer: http://www.filmweb.pl/film/Labirynt-2013-507169) ['**partial**']

Comment: does this happens with proxy or direct scrapping ?

Answer (score 0):

Its *not* partial content as such. **The rest of the content is dynamically loaded by a *Javacript AJAX call***.

To debug what content is being sent as response for a particular request, use Scrapy's **[open_in_browser()](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html#open-in-browser)** function.

There's another thread on [**How to extract dynamic content from websites that are using AJAX ?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax). Refer this for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing `['partial']` in the log means that the response is missing certain headers; see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606080/portia-spider-logs-showing-partial-during-crawling/39007029#39007029) for more detail on what causes the `partial` flag.

To catch these responses, you can simply check the [response flags](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.flags). For example, if you created the request using `Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)`, you would do the following in the callback:

```
def parse(self, response):
    if 'partial' in response.flags:
        # Do something with the response
        pass
```