# Portia Spider logs showing ['Partial'] during crawling

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd, portia

I have created a spider using **Portia** web scraper and the start URL is

```
https://www1.apply2jobs.com/EdwardJonesCareers/ProfExt/index.cfm?fuseaction=mExternal.searchJobs
```

While scheduling this spider in **scrapyd** I am getting

```
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www1.apply2jobs.com/EdwardJonesCareers/ProfExt/index.cfm?fuseaction=mExternal.searchJobs> (referer: None) ['partial']
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www1.apply2jobs.com/EdwardJonesCareers/ProfExt/index.cfm?fuseaction=mExternal.returnToResults&CurrentPage=2> (referer: https://www1.apply2jobs.com/EdwardJonesCareers/ProfExt/index.cfm?fuseaction=mExternal.searchJobs) ['partial']
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www1.apply2jobs.com/EdwardJonesCareers/ProfExt/index.cfm?fuseaction=mExternal.showJob&RID=21805&CurrentPage=1> (referer: https://www1.apply2jobs.com/EdwardJonesCareers/ProfExt/index.cfm?fuseaction=mExternal.searchJobs) ['partial']`<br><br>
```

What does the `['partial']` mean and why the content from the page is not scraped by the spdier?

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but hopefully not useless, since this behavior by scrapy doesn't seem well-documented. Looking at this [line of code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/52a52e2388e465f81e56fb92a3d731531ea6f007/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py#L410) from the scrapy source, the `partial` flag is set when the request encounters a Twisted PotentialDataLoss error. According to the corresponding [Twisted documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/9.0.0/api/twisted.web.http.PotentialDataLoss.html):

> This only occurs when making requests to HTTP servers which do not set Content-Length or a Transfer-Encoding in the response

Possible causes include:

- The server is misconfigured
- There's a proxy involved that's blocking some headers
- You get a response that doesn't normally have Content-Length, e.g. redirects (301, 302, 303), but you've set `handle_httpstatus_list` or `handle_httpstatus_all` such that the response doesn't get filtered out by HttpErrorMiddleware or fetched by RedirectMiddleware