# Selenium: What functions would fire request?

Tags: python, web-services, selenium

I am new to `Selenium` and web applications. Please bear with me for a second if my question seems way too obvious. Here is my story.

I have written a scraper in `Python` that uses `Selenium2.0 Webdriver` to crawl AJAX web pages. One of the biggest challenge (and ethics) is that I do not want to burn down the website's server. Therefore I need a way to monitor the number of requests my webdriver is firing on each page parsed.

I have done some google-searches. It seems like only `selenium-RC` provides such a functionality. However, I do not want to rewrite my code just for this reason. As a compromise, I decided to limit the rate of method calls that potentially lead to the headless browser firing requests to the server.

In the script, I have the following kind of method calls:

```
driver.find_element_by_XXXX()
driver.execute_script()
webElement.get_attribute()
webElement.text
```

I use the second function to scroll to the bottom of the window and get the AJAX content, like the following:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Based on my intuition, only the second function will trigger request firing, since others seem like parsing existing html content.

**Is my intuition wrong?**

Many many thanks

---

Perhaps I should elaborate more. I am automating a process of crawling on a website in `Python`. There is a subtantial amount of work done, and the script is running without large bugs.

My colleagues, however, reminded me that if in the process of crawling a page I made too many requests for the AJAX list within a short time, I may get banned by the server. This is why I started looking for a way to monitor the number of requests I am firing from my headless `PhantomJS` browswer **in script**.

Since I cannot find a way to monitor the number of requests **in script**, I made the compromise I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Therefore I need a way to monitor the number of requests my webdriver
>   is firing on each page parsed

As far as I know, the number of requests is depending on the webpage's design, i.e. the resources used by the webpage and the requests made by Javascript/AJAX. Webdriver will open a browser and load the webpage just like a normal user.

In Chrome, you can check the requests and responses using `Developer Tools` panel. You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax/8594831#8594831). The current UI design of `Developer Tools` is different but the basic functions are still the same. Alternatively, you can also use the `Firebug` plugin in Firefox.

---

**Updated:**

Another method to check the requests and responses is by using Wireshark. Please refer to these [Wireshark filters](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/h/http.html).

Comment: Hmm...But I am scraping a website. I cannot use Developer Tools. And I am running headless browser. I understand that number of requests depends on how long the AJAX list is. Is there a function that I can call to get the number of requests made since the first request of the page?

Comment: My question is really: Which functions would fire request? But if you can help me with the question I have above, that would make an accepted answer too:)

Comment: @Mai Sorry for late. Just now I was offline. I have updated my answer above.