# How to download infinitely-scrolling web page

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

With `WebClient.DownloadString` method it's fairly simple to load normal web page source to string.

But is there any easy way to load those pages which extends and loads new content when you scroll down to end?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: No you cannot do this with webclient.. but you can try internet explorer or webkit.net or see the ajax request being created using scroll down event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "download" such a page, as it doesn't exist in full form. Such pages require user interaction.

You can use one of the forms of the [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control to browse to, and programmatically interact with a web site.

Answer (score 1):

hey you can try this approach if you want to do it webclient..
[See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax) here.. basically he is using the [scrapy](http://scrapy.org)  but this approach can be adopted in case of webclient to i think so.

basically he is using the firebug or chrome developer tool in order to trace the ajax web request after knowing the web request you can get the content with webclient.