# Using scrapy to get the "Next Page" data

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I need to grab a commodity website's review data, but it's user data is paged .The comments per page are 10 strips , and there are about 100 pages. How can I crawl all of them out?

```
My intention is to use the yield and Request method to crawl the "Next Page" link, and then using the Xpath to extract data. But I can't jump to the next page to extract the data.
```

Here is the Html code about the "Next Page" link:

```
<div class="xs-pagebar clearfix">
     <div class="Pagecon">
          <div class="Pagenum">
               <a class="pre-page pre-disable">
               <a class="pre-page pre-disable">
               <span class="curpage">1</span>
               <a href="#" onclick="tosubmits(2):return false;">2</a>
               <a href="#" onclick="tosubmits(3);return false;">3</a>
               <span class="elli">...</span>
               <a href="#" class="next-page" onclick="tosubmits('2');return false;">Next Page</a>
               <a href="#" onclick="tosubmits('94');return false;">Final Page</a>
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

What does `href="#"` exactly mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you will not be able to do this with scrapy. `href="#"` is an anchor link that just links nowhere (to make this look like a link). What really happens is the javascript `onclick` handler that is executed. You will need to have a method of executing the javascript to do this for your use case. You might want to look into [Splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/) to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. As for that, do you know any other method to complete the work? I have been stacked by this for several days.

Comment: As i said you can either use splinter or look into the chrome dev tools to see what the JavaScript is calling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax

Comment: Thank you very much! By using Splinter, I've solved the problem! Splinter is a powerful tool to solve the dynamic web pages' problems, I like it very much!