# Python Scrapy: imitate filter click

Tags: python, scrapy

guys. I'm newbie to Scrapy and learning how to work with it. An issue occurred I can't figure out what to do next, perhaps someone more experienced will help me: I have a basic web-site with a list of items I want to parse and download. The issue is that the page has filters - pressing will filter items out. Basically I want to download data after pressing one filter but can not figure out how to do that. I noticed that pressing this filter will not change page url but the page will be reloaded so this is not ajax. Filter is marked in HTML as a link with `href="javascript:qsn.set('comm','0',1);"`. How can I imitate this filter press with Scrapy?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: examine and parse the html right off the bat. you dont have to imitate filter press.

Comment: Great advice, but the issue is that the items are not present in the list until the filter is pressed.

Comment: have you checked the html? is the item trivial?  does clicking that filter fire xhr request? otherwise you don't really have to. it would help if you posted the url

Comment: Scrapy doesn't natively support javascript, so you will not be able to click on the link.  The page is likely doing a javascript call to somewhere, and reloading the page with that data (that's AJAX, btw, even if it's not XML or asynchronous).  Use a browser to see where the call is being made, and go directly to the source (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax))

Comment: Yes, clicking that filter fire XHR. There is a GET request to specific link with query parameters. Should I make request to that link?