# unable to get the href link with scrapy 1.3.3

Tags: xpath, scrapy, linkedin-api

I am learning to use the scrapy to get the job positions information on linkedin. Now I think I can login with the scrapy, and reach the right page which contain the job link information. However, when I try to use the xpath to select the job link information, it return wrong value. Anyone can help me out?

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest

class LinkedinSpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "linkedin2"
    allowed_domains = ['linkedin.com']
    login_page = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login'
    start_url = 'http://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=data%20analyst&location=United%20States&locationId=us%3A0'

    def start_requests(self):
        self.log("start_request")
        #"""This function is called before crawling starts."""
        yield Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login, dont_filter=True)

    def login(self, response):
        #"""Generate a login request."""
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'session_key': '***@gmail.com', 'session_password': 'password'},
                    callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        #"""Check the response returned by a login request to see if we aresuccessfully logged in."""       
        if "My Network" in response.body:
            self.log("\n\n\nSuccessfully logged in. Let's start crawling!\n\n\n")
            return Request(url=self.start_url, callback=self.parse_item)

        else:
            self.log("\n\n\nFailed, Bad times :(\n\n\n")

    def parse_item(self, response):
       self.log(response.url)
       if 'Cognius' in response.body:
           self.log('***right page***')
           self.log(response.xpath("//a/@href").extract())

       else:
           self.log('***wrong page***')
```

Here is the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzJHx.png)

Here is the source of the page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft8RR.png)

Comment: Your data is probably generated with javascript. try inserting `inspect_response(response, self)` to open up shell on your page and inspect page source via `view(response)`

Answer (score 0):

Linkedin load links via ajax. You should use splash or create requests manually.
You can extract links for jobs from firebug.

[image]

Comment: Could you please give more detail about how to create request manually? Does "extract link of jobs from firebug" mean that I extract the link manually from the firebug?

Comment: @Song Check out the [top post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax) of the frequent questions from Scrapy. The answers go into some detail on how to extract content from dynamic webpages.

Comment: @rongon Thanks. I learn to use selenium and PhantomJS. However, it turns out that sometime it works, sometime it doesn't. I am trying to figure out whether it is related to the cookie. Do you know how to transfer the cookie under PhantomJS?