# Scrapy, showing description image alt

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, instagram, scrape

I tried to scrape instagram, for the example i tried to scrape nike instagram. But, ijust want get the discription of image. The description image inside tag . I tried to show it but doesn't work.

This is my code :

import scrapy

```
class Nike(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nike'
    urls = 'http://www.instagram.com/nike/'
    start_urls = [urls]
    allowed_domains = ['http://instagram.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for N in response.css('div._jjzlb'):
            yield{
                'name':N.css('alt::text').extract()
            }
```

Comment: A couple of comments: `allowed_domains` should be `['instagram.com']`, not a list of URLs ; and instagram uses JavaScript to render the page in your browser. Scrapy does not interpret JavaScript and therefore does not execute JavaScript instructions to build the response for your callbacks. You can however get a lot of data by parsing the `window._sharedData` object in the HTML source, for example using `js2xml` (disclaimer: I wrote js2xml)

Comment: Can u give me recommendation how to scrape javascript using scrapy ?What i know is using selenium, But selenium is to slow.

Comment: See my answer to grab the first 12 images

Answer (score 0):

As requested by OP in the comments, here's an example of parsing JavaScript data from the HTML source directly, using [js2xml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/js2xml/0.2.2) (disclaimer: I'm the author of js2xml):

```
$ scrapy version -v
Scrapy    : 1.4.0
lxml      : 3.7.3.0
libxml2   : 2.9.3
cssselect : 1.0.1
parsel    : 1.2.0
w3lib     : 1.17.0
Twisted   : 17.1.0
Python    : 2.7.12+ (default, Sep 17 2016, 12:08:02) - [GCC 6.2.0 20160914]
pyOpenSSL : 17.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016)
Platform  : Linux-4.8.0-53-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.10-yakkety

$ scrapy shell http://www.instagram.com/nike/
2017-05-30 10:06:39 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2017-05-30 10:06:40 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.instagram.com/nike/> from <GET http://www.instagram.com/nike/>
2017-05-30 10:06:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.instagram.com/nike/> (referer: None)

>>> response.xpath('//script[contains(., "sharedData")]')
[<Selector xpath='//script[contains(., "sharedData")]' data=u'<script type="text/javascript">window._s'>]

>>> response.xpath('string(//script[contains(., "sharedData")])').get()
u'window._sharedData = {"activity_counts": null, "config": (...redacted...) "show_app_install": true};'

>>> import js2xml   

>>> # get the JavaScript statements
>>> js = response.xpath('string(//script[contains(., "sharedData")])').get()

>>> # parse them with js2xml
>>> jstree = js2xml.parse(js)


>>> # locate the object we're interested in:
>>> # here it's the right-part of the following assignement:
>>> #                      |--- this bit
>>> # window._sharedData = {"activity_counts":...
>>>
>>> obj = jstree.xpath('//assign[left//identifier[@name="_sharedData"]]/right/*')[0]

>>> # convert this object to a Python dict
>>> sharedData = js2xml.jsonlike.make_dict(obj)
>>>
>>> from pprint import pprint

>>> # quite a lot of data...
>>> pprint(sharedData)
{'activity_counts': None,
 'config': {'csrf_token': 'JzQ8ja9YlG1cKqwAbvwacTKhOc4FuBDT', 'viewer': None},
 'country_code': 'FR',
 'display_properties_server_guess': {'pixel_ratio': 1.5,
                                     'viewport_width': 360},
 'entry_data': {'ProfilePage': [{'logging_page_id': 'profilePage_13460080',
                                 'user': {'biography': 'Just Do It.',
                                          'blocked_by_viewer': False,
                                          'connected_fb_page': None,
                                          'country_block': False,
                                          'external_url': 'http://nike.com/justdoit',
                                          'external_url_linkshimmed': 'http://l.instagram.com/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fnike.com%2Fjustdoit&e=ATOPqaPHEBPK4ylZ6YZRynSTQdp28oGedfFWw3gLtqoII1ZhtlDhLI0vu9Udbjg',
                                          'followed_by': {'count': 72447697},
                                          'followed_by_viewer': False,
                                          'follows': {'count': 136},
                                          'follows_viewer': False,
                                          'full_name': 'nike',
                                          'has_blocked_viewer': False,
                                          'has_requested_viewer': False,
                                          'id': '13460080',
                                          'is_private': False,
                                          'is_verified': True,
                                          'media': {'count': 897,
                                                    'nodes': [{'__typename': 'GraphVideo',
                                                               'caption': 'Eliud Kipchoge - 2:00:25\nThe barrier just got that much closer.\n#Breaking2 #JustDoIt',
                                                               'code': 'BTvxgGEAn-p',
                                                               'comments': {'count': 2274},
                                                               'comments_disabled': False,
                                                               'date': 1494064175,
                                                               'dimensions': {'height': 640,
                                                                              'width': 640},
                                                               'display_src': 'https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/18380674_1840678496198968_334757937257906176_n.jpg',
                                                               'id': '1508642110004428713',
                                                               'is_video': True,
                                                               'likes': {'count': 296763},
                                                               'owner': {'id': '13460080'},
                                                               'thumbnail_src': 'https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/18380674_1840678496198968_334757937257906176_n.jpg',
                                                               'video_views': 1193309},

                                                              (...redacted...)

                                                              {'__typename': 'GraphVideo',
                                                               'caption': u'We step onto the court as equals. Judged only by our performance. New Orleans sets the stage for All Star Weekend @nikebasketball.\xa0#EQUALITY #nike',
                                                               'code': 'BQlZFdugTIG',
                                                               'comments': {'count': 1172},
                                                               'comments_disabled': False,
                                                               'date': 1487273379,
                                                               'dimensions': {'height': 360,
                                                                              'width': 640},
                                                               'display_src': 'https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/16789854_771546756335957_8222167172487577600_n.jpg',
                                                               'id': '1451676781575746054',
                                                               'is_video': True,
                                                               'likes': {'count': 184595},
                                                               'owner': {'id': '13460080'},
                                                               'thumbnail_src': 'https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/c157.0.406.406/16789854_771546756335957_8222167172487577600_n.jpg',
                                                               'video_views': 627647}],
                                                    'page_info': {'end_cursor': 'AQCseCeUI_vJ_XzpTTIf7AhmwqbkBSf959347Wl03MM_ErpUQqP6RGjuJRdEcH1qJBCWvPGxUhpm6rPv5esAW5GvXHGodwmYA0eT51wnk8_-KA',
                                                                  'has_next_page': True}},
                                          'profile_pic_url': 'https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/17126848_1779368432381854_3589478532054515712_a.jpg',
                                          'profile_pic_url_hd': 'https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/17126848_1779368432381854_3589478532054515712_a.jpg',
                                          'requested_by_viewer': False,
                                          'username': 'nike'}}]},
 'environment_switcher_visible_server_guess': True,
 'gatekeepers': {'bn': True, 'ld': True, 'pl': True},
 'hostname': 'www.instagram.com',
 'language_code': 'en',
 'platform': 'web',
 'probably_has_app': False,
 'qe': {'bc3l': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'create': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'deact': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'disc': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'ebd': {'g': 'holdout', 'p': {'use_new_styles': 'false'}},
        'feed': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'gql': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'nav': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'nav_lo': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'pm': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'poe': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'profile': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'sidecar': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'su_universe': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'ufi': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'ufi_loggedout': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'us': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'us_li': {'g': '', 'p': {}},
        'video': {'g': '', 'p': {}}},
 'show_app_install': True}

>>> # nodes have a 'caption' key that looks like the "alt" attributes
>>> pprint(sharedData['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['user']['media']['nodes'])
[{'__typename': 'GraphVideo',
  'caption': 'Eliud Kipchoge - 2:00:25\nThe barrier just got that much closer.\n#Breaking2 #JustDoIt',
  'code': 'BTvxgGEAn-p',
  'comments': {'count': 2274},
  'comments_disabled': False,
  'date': 1494064175,
  'dimensions': {'height': 640, 'width': 640},
  'display_src': 'https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/18380674_1840678496198968_334757937257906176_n.jpg',
  'id': '1508642110004428713',
  'is_video': True,
  'likes': {'count': 296763},
  'owner': {'id': '13460080'},
  'thumbnail_src': 'https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/18380674_1840678496198968_334757937257906176_n.jpg',
  'video_views': 1193309},
 {'__typename': 'GraphImage',
  'caption': 'Eliud Kipchoge - 2:00:25\nThe barrier just got that much closer.\n#Breaking2 #JustDoIt',
  'code': 'BTvj_-gg6B6',
  'comments': {'count': 2269},
  'comments_disabled': False,
  'date': 1494057096,
  'dimensions': {'height': 1080, 'width': 1080},
  'display_src': 'https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/18299402_128309274385168_1749644873230712832_n.jpg',
  'id': '1508582728264818810',
  'is_video': False,
  'likes': {'count': 484745},
  'owner': {'id': '13460080'},
  'thumbnail_src': 'https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/18299402_128309274385168_1749644873230712832_n.jpg'},

(...redacted...)

 {'__typename': 'GraphVideo',
  'caption': u'We step onto the court as equals. Judged only by our performance. New Orleans sets the stage for All Star Weekend @nikebasketball.\xa0#EQUALITY #nike',
  'code': 'BQlZFdugTIG',
  'comments': {'count': 1172},
  'comments_disabled': False,
  'date': 1487273379,
  'dimensions': {'height': 360, 'width': 640},
  'display_src': 'https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/16789854_771546756335957_8222167172487577600_n.jpg',
  'id': '1451676781575746054',
  'is_video': True,
  'likes': {'count': 184595},
  'owner': {'id': '13460080'},
  'thumbnail_src': 'https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/c157.0.406.406/16789854_771546756335957_8222167172487577600_n.jpg',
  'video_views': 627647}]
>>>
```

Comment: Wow, it's awesome!! But the second question. How to scrape all of them if in one account have 100 image ??

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. It probably requires some reverse engineering of what happens in a browser, like AJAX calls and such. There are good answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax