# Scrapy: next button uses WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions()

Tags: python, asp.net, scrapy

I am trying to **scrape** some information from https://seminovos.localiza.com/Paginas/resultado-busca.aspx?&yr=2014_2019&pc=25000_500000

In this webpage, next_page button has a `href` with the following: `'javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ctl42$g_f221d036_75d3_4ee2_893d_0d7b40180245$ProximaPaginaSuperior", "", true, "", "", false, true))`

I could do that easily with Selenium, but using scrapy, how can I go to the next page?

I tried something like:

```py
next_page = response.xpath('.//a[@class="item option next"]/@href').extract_first()

if next_page:
    self.log(next_page)
    scrapy.http.FormRequest(response.url,formdata={"eventTarget":"ctl00$ctl42$g_f221d036_75d3_4ee2_893d_0d7b40180245$ProximaPaginaSuperior","eventArgument":"","validation":"true","validationGroup":"","actionUrl":"","trackFocus":"false","clientSubmit":"true"},callback=self.parse)
```

What is the proper way to navigate to next page on this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses ASP.NET, so searching a lot more and analyzing the page I found what I was looking for:

[image: post]

the final code has this format:

```py
if next_page:    
    yield FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$ctl42$g_f221d036_75d3_4ee2_893d_0d7b40180245$ProximaPagina'},callback=self.parse,dont_click=True)
```

It worked now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Find out the details of the request that your web browser performs when you click that, and try to reproduce it based on the available data.

The answers to [Can scrapy be used to scrape dynamic content from websites that are using AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8550114/939364) should give you an idea of ways to approach this. There is also [a pull request for the Scrapy documentation](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/3703/files) that covers dealing with this type of scenarios, which you might find useful.