# How can I enable JavaScript in a Scrapy URL Request?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from this site using the scrapy https://www.superbancos.gob.pa/es/fin-y-est/reportes-estadisticos?field_ano_rep_est_value=2018

but the response I get is the following html response:

> You are being redirected...
> Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.

I tried disabling the JavaScript from the Chrome Browser to see if I could get the same Scrapy Response, but it keep showing me the data.

I couldn't figure it out if I needed to change or add something to my settings.py

Could it be a Request Headers? or the agent?

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"        
    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.superbancos.gob.pa/es/fin-y-est/reportes-estadisticos?field_ano_rep_est_value=2018'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
     
    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'report-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: Scrapy has a headless browser add-on you can use for sites that require JS

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8550114/939364

Answer (score 0):

Use these headers and cookies and see the difference

```
cookies = {
    'sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_3763320b2': 'b0cda35ef63b5b3df4215f2b7902756f',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
}
```

Comment: I got the same results, I tried using scrapy-fake-useragent as well