# Scrapy, pagination and AJAX calls

Tags: python, ajax, scrapy

I try to scrape a website using Scrapy. Pagination is quite difficult because it's using AJAX and I don't know how to do.
Besides, when I click on the next page the URL doesn't chaange at all.

When I go in the network tab of the developper tool, I see this:

[image]

And this is my item code:

```
import json
import scrapy
import re
import pkgutil

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from annonces_spiders.items import AnnonceItem

class GlenMarchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'annonces_results'

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    data_file = pkgutil.get_data("annonces_spiders", "json/input/db_scrap_url_lp_js_10000_reduced.json")
    self.data = json.loads(data_file)


def start_requests(self):
    for item in self.data:
        request = scrapy.Request(item['url_lp'], callback=self.parse)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

def parse(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['results'] = []

    for caritem in response.css("li.li-result"):
        data = AnnonceItem()
        data["marque"] = caritem.css("span.brand::text").extract_first().capitalize().replace(" ", "").strip()
        data["model"] = caritem.css("span.sub-title::text").extract_first().capitalize().replace(" ", "").strip()
        data["model_year"] = caritem.css("li:nth-child(3) > div.upper::text").extract_first().replace(" ", "").strip()
        data["price_str"] = caritem.css("p.prix::text").extract_first().strip()
        if "NC" not in data["price_str"]:
            data["price_int"] = int(caritem.css("p.prix::text").extract_first().replace("€", "").replace(" ", "").strip())
        else:
            data["price_int"] = None
        data["annonce_date"] = caritem.css("p.btn-publication::text").extract_first().strip().replace("/", "-")
        data["country"] = caritem.css("div.location > img::attr(alt)").extract_first().capitalize().strip()

        item['results'].append(data)

    yield item
```

I tried to use Splash and a Lua script but the pagination seems impossible.

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to imitate the request from the Network tab? Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Nowhere, I don't understand how to do it in fact.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8550114/939364