# Scrapy - CSS selector issue

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I would like to get the link located in a `href` attribute from a `a`element. The url is: https://www.drivy.com/location-voiture/antwerpen/bmw-serie-1-477429?address=Gare+d%27Anvers-Central&city_display_name=&country_scope=BE&distance=200&end_date=2019-05-20&end_time=18%3A30&latitude=51.2162&longitude=4.4209&start_date=2019-05-20&start_time=06%3A00

I'm searching for the `href` of this element:

`<a class="car_owner_section" href="/users/2643273" rel="nofollow"></a>`

When I enter `response.css('a.car_owner_section::attr(href)').get()` in the terminal I just get nothing but the element exists even when I inspect `view(response)`.

Anybody has a clue about this issue ?

Comment: Don’t trust `view(response)`, as soon as you open the page in a browser JavaScript code can alter the DOM. Check the actual page sources (Ctrl+U in Firefox, or write `response.body` to a file). See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8550114/939364

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I already know that some data are prompted with js etc... But here I just cannot figuring out where the link is gone. It's not in any json file I've found.

Comment: It may be in the page but in a different place, in HTML. Check the sources as suggested.

Comment: Already done. I've check the full HTML code. I've maybe missed it but I don't think so. The link is rendered by JS it's certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site seems to load on JavaScript, using splash works perfect.

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class ScrapyOverflow1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "overflow1"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.drivy.com/location-voiture/antwerpen/bmw-serie-1-477429?address=Gare+d%27Anvers-Central&city_display_name=&country_scope=BE&distance=200&end_date=2019-05-20&end_time=18%3A30&latitude=51.2162&longitude=4.4209&start_date=2019-05-20&start_time=06%3A00'

        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, args={'wait': 5})

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a[@class="car_owner_section"]/@href').extract()
        print(links)
```

To use splash install splash, scrapy splash and run `sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash`

before running the spider. Here is a great article on installing and running splash. [article on scrapy spash](http://scrapingauthority.com/scrapy-javascript)... and also add midlewares to settings.py (also in the article)
[image: expected results]The result is as above

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ! I'm using scrapy with anaconda. Does this installation will be compatible with it ?

Comment: Awesome, glad i could help. Yea it is compatible. Alert me if you encounter an issue

Comment: While Splash is an option, it will have a significant performance hit on any crawling session. In the long term it’s better to figure out where the content is coming from, and extract the content directly.