# Different webpages opening using next button and href attribute of css selector

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, scrapy

If I am using the next button given on the bottom of the webpage it opens a different webpage than opening it by copying the URL in href attribute of its CSS selector on a new tab

I am making a scraper using scrapy. This is the start URL:

`https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=laptops&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off`.

Spider is working ok till page 18. From page 18 it is going to a different web page than it should go using the next button. TO check the problem i manually tried to open the webpage using the link in href but landed on a different webpage.

Following is the code to open crawl the next webpage-

```
if Spider_king.count<max_laptops:
        Spider_king.page_number+=1

        if Spider_king.page_number==2:
            Spider_king.css_selector='a._3fVaIS'
        else:
            Spider_king.css_selector='a._3fVaIS:nth-child(12)'
        next_page=response.css(Spider_king.css_selector+'::attr(href)').get()

        yield response.follow(next_page,callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Might worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You might also want to check https://stackoverflow.com/q/8550114/939364 . If JavaScript is not the issues, cookies are the likely culprit.