# how do i scrape this kind of dynamic generated website data?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to scrape E-commerce website,
example link: https://www.lazada.sg/products/esogoal-2-in-1-selfie-stick-tripod-bluetooth-selfie-stand-with-remote-shutter-foldable-tripod-monopod-i279432816-s436738661.html?mp=1

Data is being rendered via React and when i perform **scraping** on few links most of the data is being returned as `null`, and when i view the page source i cannot find actually HTML that is available via inspect element, just a json inside Javascript tags. I tested few times running scrapy **scraper** on the same links and data which was not found before, actually returns content, so its somehow randomly. I cannot figure out how should i scrape this kind of website.
As well i'm using pool of useragents and breaks between requests.

```
 script = '''
        function main(splash, args)
            assert(splash:go(args.url))
            assert(splash:wait(1.5))
            return splash:html()
        end
    '''

    def start_requests(self):
        url= [
            'https://www.lazada.sg/products/esogoal-tactical-sling-bag-outdoor-chest-pack-shoulder-backpack-military-sport-bag-for-trekking-camping-hiking-rover-sling-daypack-for-men-women-i204814494-s353896924.html?mp=1',
            'https://www.lazada.sg/products/esogoal-2-in-1-selfie-stick-tripod-bluetooth-selfie-stand-with-remote-shutter-foldable-tripod-monopod-i279432816-s436738661.html?mp=1',
            'https://www.lazada.sg/products/esogoal-selfie-stick-tripod-extendable-selfie-stick-monopod-with-integrated-tripod-and-bluetooth-remote-shutter-wireless-selfie-stick-tripod-for-cellphonecameras-i205279097-s309050125.html?mp=1',
            'https://www.lazada.sg/products/esogoal-mini-umbrella-travel-umbrella-sun-rain-umbrella8-ribs-98cm-big-surface-lightweight-compact-parasol-uv-protection-for-men-women-i204815487-s308312226.html?mp=1',
            'https://www.lazada.sg/products/esogoal-2-in-1-selfie-stick-tripod-bluetooth-selfie-stand-with-remote-shutter-foldable-tripod-monopod-i279432816-s436738661.html?mp=1'
        ]

        for link in url:
            yield SplashRequest(url=link, callback=self.parse, endpoint='render.html', args={'wait' : 0.5, 'lua_source' : self.script}, dont_filter=True)

 def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'title' : response.xpath("//span[@class='pdp-mod-product-badge-title']/text()").extract_first(),
            'price' : response.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'pdp-price')]/text()").extract_first(),
            'description' : response.xpath("//div[@id='module_product_detail']").extract_first()
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered, instead of using Splash, to go the other way and try to get the underlying data in the same way their React code does? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8550114/939364 and https://docs.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: Maybe they're blocking the requests based on the IP. Have you considered using proxies? For me it seems to work when I use a Splash instance that runs locally, but the requests from a Splash instance that runs in Google Cloud don't work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try this:

- Pass 'execute' as argument of the splash method instead of 'render html'

  ```
  from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

  class DynamicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'products'
  url = [
      'https://www.lazada.sg/products/esogoal-tactical-sling-bag-outdoor-chest-pack-shoulder-backpack-military-sport-bag-for-trekking-camping-hiking-rover-sling-daypack-for-men-women-i204814494-s353896924.html?mp=1',
      'https://www.lazada.sg/products/esogoal-2-in-1-selfie-stick-tripod-bluetooth-selfie-stand-with-remote-shutter-foldable-tripod-monopod-i279432816-s436738661.html?mp=1',
      'https://www.lazada.sg/products/esogoal-selfie-stick-tripod-extendable-selfie-stick-monopod-with-integrated-tripod-and-bluetooth-remote-shutter-wireless-selfie-stick-tripod-for-cellphonecameras-i205279097-s309050125.html?mp=1',
      'https://www.lazada.sg/products/esogoal-mini-umbrella-travel-umbrella-sun-rain-umbrella8-ribs-98cm-big-surface-lightweight-compact-parasol-uv-protection-for-men-women-i204815487-s308312226.html?mp=1',
      'https://www.lazada.sg/products/esogoal-2-in-1-selfie-stick-tripod-bluetooth-selfie-stand-with-remote-shutter-foldable-tripod-monopod-i279432816-s436738661.html?mp=1',
  ]

  script = """
      function main(splash, args)
        assert(splash:go(args.url))
        assert(splash:wait(1.5))
        return {
          html = splash:html()
        }
      end
  """

  def start_requests(self):
      for link in self.url:
          yield SplashRequest(
              url=link,
              callback=self.parse,
              endpoint='execute',
              args={'wait': 0.5, 'lua_source': self.script},
              dont_filter=True,
          )

  def parse(self, response):
      yield {
          'title': response.xpath("//span[@class='pdp-mod-product-badge-title']/text()").extract_first(),
          'price': response.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'pdp-price')]/text()").extract_first(),
          'description': response.xpath("//div[@id='module_product_detail']/h2/text()").extract_first()
      }
  ```

---

An this is the result
[image]