# Scrapy does not fetch markup on response.css

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapinghub, splash-js-render

I've built a simple scrapy spider running on scrapinghub:

```
class ExtractionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "extraction"
    allowed_domains = ['domain']
    start_urls = ['http://somedomainstart']
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css('a.offer-details__title-link::attr(href)').extract()

        print(urls)
        for url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

        multiple_locs_urls = response.css('a.offer-regions__label::attr(href)').extract()
        print(multiple_locs_urls)        
        for url in multiple_locs_urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

        next_page_url = response.css('li.pagination_element--next > a.pagination_trigger::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield SplashRequest(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self, response): 
        yield {
        'title': response.css('#jobTitle').extract_first(),
        'content': response.css('#description').extract_first(),
        'datePosted': response.css('span[itemprop="datePosted"]').extract_first(),
        'address': response.css('span[itemprop="address"]').extract_first()
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that the multiple_locs_url response.css returns an empty array despite me seeing it in the markup on the browser side.

I checked with scrapy shell and scrapy shell does not see the markup. I guess this is due to the markup being rendered through javascript when the page is loaded.

I added splash but that does not seem to apply to response. How would I make scrapy wait with the query until the page is loaded?

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: Can you provide the URL and explain what exactly you want to scrape in it?

Comment: Did you try different value for the `wait` parameter of Spash  like for example `SPLASH_ARGS = {'wait': 2}` (in the spider class definition) ?

Comment: without `URL` i don't think we can help you .. there can be number of factors 

1 ) are you using same browser which useragent you are using ( in some cases website send different response to different browsers.
2 ) Maybe content is loading though AJAX call or what ever

so share uRL to help you out

Comment: @akhter wahab My start url is http://pracuj.pl/praca/polska;ct,1 I already tried all kind of configurations, including timing or executing the request with splash and then try to query the response but none seems to work. The user agent is correctly set.

Comment: see: view-source:https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/polska;ct,1 ; there is no element with class "offer-regions__label" in html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See source code for the page: view-source:pracuj.pl/praca/polska;ct,1 .
There is no element with class "offer-regions__label" in html code.

This code will always return an empty list:

```
multiple_locs_urls = response.css('a.offer-regions__label::attr(href)')
```

But as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17697329/9913319:

> Many times when crawling we run into problems where content that is
>   rendered on the page is generated with Javascript and therefore scrapy
>   is unable to crawl for it.

In this case you can use Selenium.
I changed your code and checked it and it works:

```
class ExtractionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "extraction"
    allowed_domains = ['domain']
    start_urls = ['http://somedomainstart']
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"

    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):

        super().__init__( **kwargs )

        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile( "pathToFirefoxProfile" )
        firefox_binary = "pathToFirefoxBinary"  # Must be the developer edition!!!
        # self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox( profile, firefox_binary = firefox_binary )

    def parse(self, response):

        self.driver.get( response.url )

        elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector( "a.offer-details__title-link" )
        self.driver.get( response.url )
        for element in elements:
            print( "****" )
            print( str( element.get_attribute( "href" ) ) )
            print( str( element.text ) )

        # your old code below

        urls = response.css('a.offer-details__title-link::attr(href)').extract()

        print(urls)
        for url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

        multiple_locs_urls = response.css('a.offer-regions__label::attr(href)').extract()
        print(multiple_locs_urls)        
        for url in multiple_locs_urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

        next_page_url = response.css('li.pagination_element--next > a.pagination_trigger::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield SplashRequest(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self, response): 
        yield {
        'title': response.css('#jobTitle').extract_first(),
        'content': response.css('#description').extract_first(),
        'datePosted': response.css('span[itemprop="datePosted"]').extract_first(),
        'address': response.css('span[itemprop="address"]').extract_first()
        }
```

Comment: `view-source:...` shows only the HTML as it is downloaded by the initial request, not the fully rendered DOM. That's why he is using Splash already