# Scrapy empty information on a website with protection

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am struggling on a website to get some information, I set up `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` but still doesnt retrieve any information, how to fix it?

```
start_urls = ['https://tienda.mercadona.es/search-results?query=leche%20entera']

def parse(self, response):
    sample = response.css("div").get()
    yield {'name':sample}
```

Thank you so much, as far as I see, probably they have something to forbid me when I do the request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can scrapy be used to scrape dynamic content from websites that are using AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you are trying to scrape is dynamically loaded with JavaScript. Vanilla Scrapy won't handle javascript by default but there are plugins that may help. A simple one that comes to mind is [Scrapy-Playwright](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright). Once configured properly it usually just requires adding DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS to the settings.py file like so:

```
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
"http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
"https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
```

}

You will then need to pass `meta={"playwright":True}` as an argument within the scrapy Request.

Comment: what about twisted reactor? should i install it? Thank you so much

Comment: also i am not doing any request on the scrapy, its every on parse() method

Comment: Twisted reactor is used by vanilla scrapy and won't change anything. You need scrapy-playwright because you need the page to be loaded with javascript before being sent back in the response object. the parse() method receives the response object.

Comment: sorry its not enough this code and I couldnt manage to get the info, at the end I did it by requests library, thank you anyway