# xpath issue in nested div

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

New to python/scrapy. I am testing responses via xpath in the console and am able to print the h1 header as a test using the code below. **Now I am trying to select the xpath to pull the (1) job title, (2) job URL**

Here is my console code:

```
    r = scrapy.Request(url='https://www.northropgrumman.com/jobs?remote=yes-may-consider-full-time-teleworking-for-this-position&country=united-states-of-america&_job_category=global-supply-chain,business-management,program-management')
    
    fetch(r)

     #this works and pulls "Job Search" header at top of page
    response.xpath('//h1/text()').getall()
    
    # broken, tried many combos of xpaths to get job title and url
    response.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/a/text()").getall()
```

What is the xpath for job titles and job URLs on the jobs listed on this page?

https://www.northropgrumman.com/jobs?remote=yes-may-consider-full-time-teleworking-for-this-position&country=united-states-of-america&_job_category=global-supply-chain,business-management,program-management

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample. Linked content can expire, rendering the question meaningless for future readers, and images are both less accessible and do not permit people to interact with the code/configuration/etc in your question.

Comment: Your xpath selector is too complicated, maybe try to do [something](https://devhints.io/xpath) more simple. *BUT* even if your xpath is good the website loads the data dynamically so you'll need to get the data in [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax).

Answer (score 0):

XPath for job titles could be :

`//div[@class="col-sm-9"]/a/@href`

For job URLs :

`//div[@class="col-sm-9"]/a/h2/text()`

One liner for both :

`//div[@class="col-sm-9"]/a/@href|//div[@class="col-sm-9"]/a/h2/text()`

Results :

```
href="/jobs/Business-Management/Contract/United-States-of-America/Virginia/Fairfax/R10151186/principal-sr-principal-contract-administrator"
​#text "Principal / Sr Principal Contract Administrator"
​href="/jobs/Business-Management/Contract/United-States-of-America/California/Sunnyvale/R10153611/principal-senior-principal-contract-administrator-hybrid-or-full-time-remote-schedule"
​#text "Principal / Senior Principal Contract Administrator (Hybrid or Full Time Remote Schedule)"
​href="/jobs/Business-Management/Multi-Function/United-States-of-America/Maryland/Linthicum/R10150106/principal-pricing-analyst"
​#text "Principal Pricing Analyst"
...
```

Comment: It won't work with Scrapy because the data is loaded dynamically.

Comment: Sure. The question was related to the XPaths. Scrapy+Selenium'll do the trick. Otherwise, just download the .json from `https://discover.sitecorecloud.io/discover/v2/136346287` with the correct credentials and pull out the data from it.