# using Scrapy to get hidden elements

Tags: html, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to get comments from articles.

For example, [testPage](http://techcrunch.com/2012/07/28/not-that-kind-of-filthy-get-your-mind-out-of-the-gutter/) has comments at the end of the article.

How would I be able to get access to those comments?
It appears that the html downloaded by scrapy does not contain references to the comments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know scrapy sees a webpage with javascript disabled and those are facebook comments, that is they are pulled through javascript on that page.

You might want to take a look here [How to combine scrapy and htmlunit to crawl urls with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047666/how-to-combine-scrapy-and-htmlunit-to-crawl-urls-with-javascript)