# how to use webkit code in scrapy/python

Tags: python, webkit, scrapy

In the question at [How to combine scrapy and htmlunit to crawl urls with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047666/how-to-combine-scrapy-and-htmlunit-to-crawl-urls-with-javascript), it is advised to use webkit with scrapy to go through javascript.
However, this [example Snipplr snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/66996/renderedinteractive-javascript-with-gtkwebkitjswebkit/) says:

```
import gtk
import webkit
import jswebkit
```

I am new to Python. From whatever I understand, webkit (written in C/C++ ) needs to have Python wrappers. I looked around but could not find anything like that. Any advise appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest example you can start here

```
import gtk 
import webkit 

view = webkit.WebView() 

sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow() 
sw.add(view) 

win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL) 
win.add(sw) 
win.show_all() 

view.open("http://w3.org/") 
gtk.main()
```

You can learn more from here http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/
Also have a look here 
http://dvlabs.tippingpoint.com/blog/2011/11/28/malicious-content-harvesting